# Clojure convert {"a.b" 1, "a.c" 2, "d.e" 3} to {:a {:b 1, :c 2}, :d {:e 3}} (for compojure/hiccup with monger hierarchy)

Tags: clojure, compojure, hiccup, monger

My mongodb schema has a JSON hierarchy to it.  When I get the field params from compojure, the hash is in flat dotted notation like `{"a.b" 1, "a.c" 2, "d.e" 3}`.  I'm wanting to use monger to insert the data, but that expects a real hierarchical format like `{:a {:b 1, :c 2}, :d {:e 3}}`.  Is there any way to automatically convert from one to the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing automatic that I know of, but it's pretty straightforward to do the conversion manually:

```
=> (require 'clojure.string)
=> (defn nest-keys [x]
     (reduce (fn [m [k v]]
               (assoc-in m (map keyword (clojure.string/split k #"\.")) v))
             {}
             x))
=> (nest-keys {"a.b" 1 "a.c" 2 "d.e" 3})
{:d {:e 3}, :a {:c 2, :b 1}}
```

Comment: Really great!  Any chance you can come up with an equally succinct reverse conversion?

Comment: Logic for the reverse is a bit trickier but here's what I came up with: https://gist.github.com/alexhall/5799651